# How to multiply vectors of different sized lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, vector, apply

I'm trying to multiply vectors contained in a list by another vector in another list.

The elements of each list are different sizes.

The lists to multiply are the `Concat_list` and `List_3`:

```
set.seed(10)
List_1 <- rep(list(matrix(runif(10), nrow = 10, ncol = 1)), 2)
List_2 <- rep(list(matrix(runif(10), nrow = 10, ncol = 1)), 2)
Concat_list <- lapply(seq(List_1), function(i) {
  matrix(mapply(c, List_1[[i]], List_2[[i]], SIMPLIFY = F) )  })
List_3 <- list(c(50, 25), c(10, 18))
```

How do I multiply each row of each element of the `Concat_list` by the respective vector of `List_3`?

i.e.:

```
Concat_list[[1]][[1]] * List_3[[1]]
Concat_list[[1]][[2]] * List_3[[1]]
Concat_list[[1]][[3]] * List_3[[1]]
# ...etc
Concat_list[[2]][[1]] * List_3[[2]]
Concat_list[[2]][[2]] * List_3[[2]]
# ...etc
```

I have tried:

```
lapply(seq(Concat_list), function(i){
  lapply(Concat_list[[i]], function(x){
  x[[i]] * List_3[[i]]
  }) 
})

lapply(seq(Concat_list), function(i){
  sapply(Concat_list[[i]], function(x){
    x[[i]] * List_3[[i]]
  })
})

Test <- lapply(seq(Concat_list), function(i) {
  matrix(mapply(function(x, y){x*y}, Concat_list[[i]], List_3[[i]], SIMPLIFY = F) )  })

Test_2 <- rep(list(matrix(nrow = nrow(Concat_list[[1]]), ncol = 1)) , length(Concat_list) )
for(i in seq(Concat_list)){
  for(j in seq(Concat_list[[i]])){
    Test_2[[i]][j] <- unlist(Concat_list[[i]][j]) * List_3[[i]]
  }
}

Map('*', Concat_list[[1]], List_3[[1]])
```

None of these quite work, and the double-for loop is something I'm trying to avoid.

I've also tried putting `unlist()` in various places with no luck.

Here is the expected output in a for loop for the first element of `Concat_list`:

`# Correct
for(i in 1:10){print(unlist(Concat_list[[1]][i]) * List_3[[1]])}`

And the same thing but more explicitly stated.

```
c(0.5074782, 0.6516557) * List_3[[1]]
c(0.3067685, 0.5677378) * List_3[[1]]
c(0.4269077, 0.1135090) * List_3[[1]]
```

Thanks

Comment: as suggested by @mt1022 - maybe it would be a good idea to turn that list into a matrix prior to the computation eg. via: `t(matrix(unlist(Concat_list), nrow = 2))`; otherwise great answer by @mt1022

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
res <- Map(
    function(x, y){ as.matrix(lapply(x, function(i){ i * y })) },
    Concat_list, List_3)
```

here is part of the final results:

```
> res[[1]][[1]]
[1] 25.37391 16.29139
> res[[1]][[2]]
[1] 15.33843 14.19344
> res[[2]][[1]]
[1]  5.074782 11.729802
> res[[2]][[2]]
[1]  3.067685 10.219280
```

In my opinion, your `Concat_list` is too complicated. Maybe you can simplify it to a list of 10x2 matrices.